# encoding from .txt file to string using php

Tags: php

I'm doing this project where I receive a .txt file from a MATLAB program in a PHP server. I would like to extract the data in the .txt file and encode it to a string to be sent by the server to an android. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: You will have to elaborate on the data format and expected outcome, if you don't just want it to be written out as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Screw the string.

[`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Answer (score 0):

use below code for your task.

```
$file = file_get_contents('test.txt', true);
$parsed_str = json_decode($file);
```

I think it may be helpful to you..

Thanks.